# Is there a way to configure the Application Pool's "Idle timeout" in web.config?

Tags: iis, web-config, application-pool, python-idle

I know one can set the session timeout. But, if the application itself has received no requests for a given period of time, IIS shuts down the application.

This behavior is configurable in the IIS management console, and I know how to do this. Still, I wonder if it is possible to configure this in web.config.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in IIS 6.  In IIS 6, Application Pools are controlled by Worker Processes, which map to a Request Queue handled by HTTP.sys.  HTTP.sys handles the communication with the WWW Server to determine when to start and stop Worker Processes.

Since IIS 6 was created before .Net, there's no communication hooks between .Net and the low-level http handlers.

ASP.net is implimented as an ISAPI filter, which is loaded by the Worker Process itself.  You have a chicken-before-the-egg issue if you are looking at the web.config controlling a worker process.  This is primarily why MS did the major re-write of IIS 7 which integrates .Net through the entire request life-cycle, not just the ISAPI filter portion.

Answer (score 3):

You can edit these settings, but not in web.config.  If you have IIS7, the setting is in applicationHost.config, and the key attribute is the **shutdownTimeLimit**.
You can google for it, to find out how to use appcmd and other tools to set or change it.

[Example](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/processModel)

Also you can directly modify the shutdownTimeLimit by editing the applicationHost.config file, which is in the \inetsrv\config directory.

The schema for the applicationHost.config file is in the \inetsrv\config\schema\IIS_schema.xml file.
So open it in your favorite schema-aware XML editor and you'll get intellisense, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with  setting IdleTimeout.
**BUT** changes to the processModel element take effect only when the worker process is restarted—not immediately after the setting is changed, as with other configuration elements.
You can see it here:
[processModel Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1.aspx)

You also must change machene.config to can edit machine configuration from other archive.